# Java initialising a static field to itself

Tags: java

This code compiles (using Java 8), giving the warning `The assignment to variable value has no effect`:

```
package test;

public class Test {
    private static int value;

    static {
        value = Test.value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

The program outputs `0` as expected. But why does the compiler allow this, what is the use case?

Comment: Well, it warns you that it's pointless anyway, I guess it would be intrusive not to allow someone to write something obvious, it is not really affecting the flow of your program so why would you expect a compilation error?

Comment: there is a use case for it, see my answer below...

Comment: @Andrew Moss nice that you accept an answer, which does not answer your  Question what is the use case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because variables in Java have a default value which is initialized before any other initialization, unless the initialization happens directly when declaring the variable. Indeed `value` is `0`.

The warning seems reasonable, assigning a variable to itself has no apparent effect but I don't think it should be considered a compile type error since it's syntactically and semantically correct.

Comment: and what is the usecase?

Comment: @FelixLahmer: the same use case of `if (true)`. Correct code (from a compiler point of view) doesn't mean useful code. Should `if (true)` raise an error too?

Comment: Fair enough. It looks weirder if you declare and initialise the field on the same line. With a static initialiser it's a bit clearer what's going on.

Comment: @AndrewMoss What wierd in that ?It is good practice to initialize variables when you decalre them, it ensures no garbage values or compiler errors later on.

Comment: @Mustafasabir Good practice to initialise fields to themselves pointlessly like this?! `private static int value = Test.value;'

Comment: @AndrewMoss not that, but `declare and initialise the field on the same line` usually means `private static int value = 0;` .Your snippet `private static int value = Test.value;` is more of `equating field to themselves` (which will have no effect).

Comment: @Mustafasabir there is no effect on the value but theres an effect of concurrency when using different threads and volatile....

Comment: @jack assigning a variable to itself has no effect , this is wrong

Answer (score 1):

If as variable is assigned to itself, the compiler issues a warning, as in the following:

```
  int x = 2;

  x = x;
```

This warning is usually a sign of a programming problem, so for itself it is a good thing to have it, yet in the case that the variable is volatile, which will be the **ONLIEST** useful **Use Case** I can think off, the warning is incorrect.

```
  int y = 0;
  volatile int x = 2;
  y = 3;
  x = x;
```

The java memory model enforces that every thread reading x and y in that order is guaranteed to see the value 3 for y. This is because assigning to x in one thread and reading x in the other establishes a happens-before-ordering.

*The assignment has no effect to the value of the variable but it does have a huge effect for concurrency.*

Note that in the example above the warning can be suppressed by using

```
 x = x + 0;
```

Yet there is no such hack for references. One Use Case that will hit you is when trying to sync the content of a `int[]`. One thread reads a member:

```
myarray[3]
```

and another thread writes the member:

```
myarray[3] = 2;
```

Because array members themselfes cannot be volatile, you have to make `myarray` volatile and add the following to the writing thread:

```
myarrray = myarray;
```